# google PageSpeed Insights inconsistent result

Tags: pagespeed

When I test facebook with google PageSpeed Insights, I am getting highly inconsistent results. It gives different result for http://facebook.com, https://facebook.com, www.facebook.com, ... and also sometimes it is showing different result at different time for the exact same url. (The results are shown very poor most of the time and facebook it is)

Why is this happening?. Is it facebook behaving differently at different times?.

Comment: Facebook loads lots of data in the background and then puts it into the DOM; the initial page load only loads a very basic “shell” document. And what/how much data is loaded, is of course highly dynamic, because of different state of your news feed, friends that are online in chat, etc. pp.

Comment: FYI, this question hardly deserves the `facebook` tag (removed). Please read tag descriptions, and tag appropriately.

Comment: @CBroe: the page which I am testing is facebook login page which may not not be that dynamic. Your answer makes sense when the testing is done at home page.

Comment: Well, I have seen that on [ThinkwithGoogle](http://testmysite.thinkwithgoogle.com/) or with [PageSpeedOptimizer](https://pagespeedoptimizer.com/), they used PageSpeed Insights result. But I didn't found any such type of issue there.

Answer (score 1):

Refer the [page](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about)
Why does the performance score change from run to run? I didn’t change anything on my page!

Variability in performance measurement is introduced via a number of channels with different levels of impact. Several common sources of metric variability are local network availability, client hardware availability, and client resource contention.